# Converting CvSeq to CvMat

Tags: opencv, matrix, sequence

I have a sequence of CvPoint2D32f points in CvSeq and I want to convert it into a CvMat. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `cvSeqToArray`.  It will dump the sequence to a contiguous array of any type (in your case, it will be float).  You can then create a matrix header for that array by using `cvCreateMatHeader`.